# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when running any LWJGL code

Tags: java, lwjgl

I can't run anything that is openGL related without getting this exception (even with exact copy-paste code from this [tutorial](http://thecodinguniverse.com/lwjgl-window/)). I updated jre to 1.8 as well as updated drivers, but that didn't solve any problems. How to solve this? Log file:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x066a3c00, pid=5140, tid=4188

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x066a3c00

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00c84000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4188, stack(0x00f30000,0x00f80000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x00000008 0x066a3c00

Registers:
EAX=0xe2616b4a, EBX=0x064e2940, ECX=0x06498300, EDX=0x00000004
ESP=0x00f7f14c, EBP=0x06480320, ESI=0x05a770c0, EDI=0x00f7f19c
EIP=0x066a3c00, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00f7f14c)
0x00f7f14c:   04478ec3 064e2940 06480320 00000000
0x00f7f15c:   00f7f204 066991a4 00000001 00000004
0x00f7f16c:   064810a0 066a1ad4 00000000 ffffffff
0x00f7f17c:   00000001 00000001 00000000 066a3c00
0x00f7f18c:   00000000 06480320 05a770c0 06498300
0x00f7f19c:   e2616b4a 0002ffb1 04d011f0 00f7f1e0
0x00f7f1ac:   04d17da8 0446578e 04d34bf0 00f7f1d0
0x00f7f1bc:   044836d4 00f7f19c 00000000 00001fa0 

Instructions: (pc=0x066a3c00)
0x066a3be0:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 19 59 dc ac 61 81 3f 08
0x066a3bf0:   00 00 00 00 f0 3b 6a 06 05 05 00 00 01 00 00 00
0x066a3c00:   55 8b ec 53 56 57 8b d9 8b ca 8b 75 08 81 e1 fc
0x066a3c10:   ff ff ff 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 90 66 66 66 66 66 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0xe2616b4a is an unknown value
EBX=0x064e2940 is an unknown value
ECX=0x06498300 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000004 is an unknown value
ESP=0x00f7f14c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00c84000
EBP=0x06480320 is an unknown value
ESI=0x05a770c0 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00f7f19c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00c84000


Stack: [0x00f30000,0x00f80000],  sp=0x00f7f14c,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x066a3c00

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglClear(IJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear(I)V+15
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.initContext(FFF)V+10
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.initContext()V+12
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/Drawable;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs;)V+111
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+12
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create()V+7
j  pack.opengl.<init>()V+20
j  pack.opengl.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00d26400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5868, stack(0x03f60000,0x03fb0000)]
  0x00d16c00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4796, stack(0x01210000,0x01260000)]
  0x00d15c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3524, stack(0x012d0000,0x01320000)]
  0x00d12800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5292, stack(0x01280000,0x012d0000)]
  0x00cab800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=476, stack(0x011c0000,0x01210000)]
  0x00ca6400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8172, stack(0x01110000,0x01160000)]
=>0x00c84000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4188, stack(0x00f30000,0x00f80000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00ca4c00 VMThread [stack: 0x010b0000,0x01100000] [id=4692]
  0x00d40800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x040a0000,0x040f0000] [id=6300]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 2719K [0x24c00000, 0x25150000, 0x2a150000)
  eden space 4416K,  61% used [0x24c00000, 0x24ea7f30, 0x25050000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x25050000, 0x25050000, 0x250d0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x250d0000, 0x250d0000, 0x25150000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x2a150000, 0x2ac00000, 0x34c00000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x2a150000, 0x2a150000, 0x2a150200, 0x2ac00000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 828K [0x34c00000, 0x35800000, 0x38c00000)
   the space 12288K,   6% used [0x34c00000, 0x34ccf0a0, 0x34ccf200, 0x35800000)
    ro space 10240K,  42% used [0x38c00000, 0x39034650, 0x39034800, 0x39600000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x39600000, 0x39c4be40, 0x39c4c000, 0x3a200000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00e80000,0x00f30000] byte_map_base: 0x00d5a000

Polling page: 0x00800000

Code Cache  [0x01f50000, 0x01ff0000, 0x03f50000)
 total_blobs=230 nmethods=42 adapters=126 free_code_cache=32129Kb largest_free_block=32900928

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 1.049 Thread 0x00d16c00   38             java.nio.Buffer::position (43 bytes)
Event: 1.050 Thread 0x00d16c00 nmethod 38 0x01fee488 code [0x01fee590, 0x01fee69c]
Event: 1.050 Thread 0x00d16c00   39             java.nio.Bits::byteOrder (20 bytes)
Event: 1.050 Thread 0x00d16c00 nmethod 39 0x01fee708 code [0x01fee800, 0x01fee870]
Event: 1.053 Thread 0x00d16c00   40             org.lwjgl.MemoryUtil$CharSequenceNT::length (12 bytes)
Event: 1.053 Thread 0x00d16c00 nmethod 40 0x01fee8c8 code [0x01fee9d0, 0x01feea6c]
Event: 1.079 Thread 0x00d16c00   41             java.nio.Buffer::limit (62 bytes)
Event: 1.079 Thread 0x00d16c00 nmethod 41 0x01feeac8 code [0x01feebd0, 0x01feecec]
Event: 1.079 Thread 0x00d16c00   42             java.nio.Buffer::<init> (121 bytes)
Event: 1.080 Thread 0x00d16c00 nmethod 42 0x01feed88 code [0x01feef40, 0x01fef434]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.983 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24dfaed0 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.984 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24dffcf8 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.985 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24e03018 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.987 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24e06078 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.988 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24e0b7f8 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.989 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24e0e628 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.991 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24e11658 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.007 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24e24268 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.091 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24e9abd8 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 1.093 Thread 0x00c84000 Threw 0x24e9df10 at C:\re\jdk7u67\1368\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.990 loading class 0x3a32d360
Event: 0.990 loading class 0x3a32d360 done
Event: 0.991 loading class 0x00d410b8
Event: 0.991 loading class 0x00d410b8 done
Event: 1.007 loading class 0x0411b1b8
Event: 1.007 loading class 0x0411b1b8 done
Event: 1.091 loading class 0x0411e1f0
Event: 1.091 loading class 0x0411e1f0 done
Event: 1.093 loading class 0x00d667c0
Event: 1.093 loading class 0x00d667c0 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x01320000 - 0x0134f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x779a0000 - 0x77ac8000     C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
0x76040000 - 0x7611c000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77710000 - 0x777d6000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77b30000 - 0x77bf3000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x767a0000 - 0x7683d000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x77ae0000 - 0x77b2b000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x74d90000 - 0x74f2e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.6002.18305_none_5cb72f2a088b0ed3\COMCTL32.dll
0x777e0000 - 0x7788a000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76740000 - 0x76799000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x766d0000 - 0x766ee000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76a30000 - 0x76af8000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x76320000 - 0x76329000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.DLL
0x77890000 - 0x7790d000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x6d580000 - 0x6d59a000     c:\progra~1\kasper~1\kasper~1\mzvkbd3.dll
0x76030000 - 0x76037000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x65370000 - 0x6542f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x5c280000 - 0x5c608000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x72be0000 - 0x72be7000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x76330000 - 0x7635d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x76290000 - 0x76296000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x74b20000 - 0x74b52000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x764f0000 - 0x76635000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x77910000 - 0x7799d000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x74ae0000 - 0x74b1e000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEACC.dll
0x729e0000 - 0x729ec000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x72970000 - 0x72990000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x698f0000 - 0x69903000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x10000000 - 0x1004d000     C:\Users\vaikai\workspace\swingvsopengl\lib\natives\lwjgl.dll
0x652a0000 - 0x6536b000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x698b0000 - 0x698d3000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x6c390000 - 0x6c475000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x6c7d0000 - 0x6c7d6000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x76360000 - 0x764ea000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x730c0000 - 0x730cc000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x756d0000 - 0x756d8000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x043f0000 - 0x04cf7000     C:\Windows\system32\atioglxx.dll
0x6c480000 - 0x6c4e2000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x74530000 - 0x74572000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x75ef0000 - 0x75f0e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75ed0000 - 0x75ee4000     C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll
0x6d660000 - 0x6d698000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x6f640000 - 0x6f71c000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\vaikai\workspace\swingvsopengl\lib\natives -Dfile.encoding=Cp1257 
java_command: pack.opengl
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;"C:\Program Files\Pinnacle\Shared Files\InstantCDDVD\";C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\FPC\2.4.4\bin\i386-Win32;C:\Users\vaikai\Desktop\arvydo\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32\eclipse;
USERNAME=vaikai
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 22 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Vista Build 6002 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 22 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 1964548k(459748k free), swap 3964276k(392144k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_67-b01), built on Jul 25 2014 10:20:53 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Fri Aug 15 11:59:21 2014
elapsed time: 1 seconds
```

Comment: Potential Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147639/exception-access-violation-0xc0000005-when-trying-to-free-memory

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate, because I cannot execute ANY opengl code. Meanwhile a guy in that thread has problems with specificly his code.

Comment: Have you tried running any of the games from [LWJGL Projects](http://lwjgl.org/projects.php)? Do they give the same error? If yes: can you run any non-LWJGl application?

Comment: Where did you get the libglesv2.dll? I'm having same issue. Will try more.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this when I did anything OpenGL related (like even allocating a VBO or texture) without calling `GL.createCapabilities();` beforehand. As soon as I made that call after setting up GLFW, all my problems went away.

This is as of LWJGL 3.1.2 though, not earlier versions.